# Unabale to extract p-value from my betadisper, comes back NULL

Tags: r, p-value, statistical-test

I successfully ran my community data in R to make my NMDS figures and also successfully ran my statistical tests. However, when I try to extract my p-value from betadisper it comes back as NULL. Could someone please help me with this?

I have attached the relevant code:

```
# Perform permutational multivariate analysis of variance (PERMANOVA) using adonis
adonis_result <- adonis2(diss_matrix ~ Clipping_Treatment * Dominant_Species, data = DensEnv)

# Calculate distance-based redundancy analysis (db-RDA) using betadisper
betadisper_result <- betadisper(diss_matrix, DensEnv$Clipping_Treatment)


# Print results
print(adonis_result)
print(betadisper_result)
```

this is what comes back `NULL`:

```
perm_test <- permutest(betadisper_result, permutations = 999)
p_value <- perm_test$signif
```